# Функция Эйлера. time-limit-exceeded

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, c++14, теория-чисел

Программа реализует функцию Эйлера ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Функция_Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)), вроде всё работает, на тестах проверял - ошибок не возникало на достаточно больших числах в том числе.

Единственная проблема - не могу сдать программу ввиду time-limit-exceeded (на первых 9 тестах всё работает за 2 миллисекунды, а на 10-м тесте - 3.076 секунду). Макс. ограничение во времени - 3 секунды. Прошу помочь, может кто найдет где у меня в программе это может происходить?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binomialCoeff(int k, int n)  
{ 
    if (k == 0 || k == n)  
        return 1;  
  
    return binomialCoeff(k - 1, n - 1) +  
        binomialCoeff(k, n - 1);  
}

int gsd(int a, int b) {
    while(a!=0 && b!=0) {
        if(a>b) a%=b;
        else b%=a;
    }
    return a+b;
}

int Euler(unsigned long k, unsigned long n) {
    unsigned int result=1; 
    int combination = binomialCoeff(k,n);
    for(int i=2; i<=combination; i++) {
        if(gsd(i,combination) == 1) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int k, n;
    cin >> k >> n;
    if(k<0 || n<0 || n<k) 
        throw invalid_argument("Binom condition failed");
    cout << Euler(k,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/euler_function

Comment: так предполагаю проблема в функции binomialCoeff, можно попробовать еще сюда мемоизацию влепить

Comment: @вася попробовал по алгоритму как на сайте, выдает всё те же 3.076 секунд на 10 тесте.

Comment: Функция Эйлера - это тот секрет на котором основана стойкость RSA. Чтобы определить ФЭ от натурального числа - его надо разложить на простые множители. Когда много маленьких множителей - задача решается быстро, а самый тяжелый случай - разложение на два простых множителя примерно равного порядка. Возможно у Вас в 10-м тесте тяжёлый случай. Тем более, что вы в функции binomialCoeff(...) используете рекурсию. сделайте алгоритм факторизации попроще: перебор, ро-метрод Полларда или на очень больших числах - квадратичное решето в числовом поле.

Comment: Думаю, что эта ссылка может помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459934/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ad%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Что-то как-то странно вы ее вычисляете... И потом, что-то я по ссылке не нашел никакой функции Эйлера от двух переменных. Так что уточните, о том ли я отвечаю, о чем вы спрашиваете? :)

Недавно пришлось [писать ее на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1139615/195342), вот перевод на C/C++:

```
unsigned long long fi(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long f = n;
    if (n%2 == 0)
    {
        while (n%2 == 0) n /= 2;
        f/= 2;
    }
    for(unsigned long long i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            while (n%i == 0) n /= i;
            f /= i;
            f *= (i-1);
        }
    }
    if (n > 1)
    {
        f /= n;
        f *= (n-1);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Это то, что вам нужно?

На таком неприятном числе, как 187917426909946969 (квадрат простого числа, т.е. полный перебор), у меня на машине работает примерно 1.61±0.02 с.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int binomialCoeff(int k, int n)
> { 
>     if (k == 0 || k == n)  
>         return 1;  
>   
>     return binomialCoeff(k - 1, n - 1) +  
>         binomialCoeff(k, n - 1);  
> }
> ```

У этой функции экспоненциальная сложность. Вместо этого лучше считать по формуле.

Comment: Биномиальный коэффициент легко разложить на простые. По разложению функция Эйлера считается элементарно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а как это к моему ответу относится?

Comment: Глупость написал. Я предполагал что функция Эйлера будет значительно меньше самого коэффициента. В этом случае эффективно считать коэффициенты не надо - их вообще считать  не надо. Но это не так: функция Эйлера сравнима по порядку величины с самим коэффициентом. А значит быстрый расчёт может иметь смысл. Вы правы в своём ответе.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а что вообще за функция эйлера? Та, которую я могу нагуглить, принимает только один аргумент, а в вопросе почему-то два.

Comment: Имелась в виду обычная функция Эйлера от `Cnk(n, k)` (число комбинаций).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, тогда, наверное, ты прав и лучше факторизовать факториалы, а потом просто вычислить функцию эйлера по формуле для факторизованного числа.

Comment: Так и есть. Но такой нюанс: если ф.Эйлер(Cnk(n, k)) помещается в `uint64_t`, то `Cnk(n, k)` факторизуется достаточно быстро.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну у него вообще вычисление gcd на каждой итерации цикла, так что явно быстро не будет. Ну и в любом случае, по формуле быстрее. Да и вообще, а кто сказал, что оно помещяется в 64?

Answer (score 0):

Функция Эйлера от биномиального коэффициента φ(cnk(n, k)) вычисляется без нахождения самого коэффициента. Надо перебрать все простые, для каждого простого числа найти степень с которой оно входит в биномиальный коэффициент. Коэффициент - комбинация трёх факториалов `cnk(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n - k)!)`. Для факториала [степень простого находится просто](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8):

```
// степень s такая что n! делится на p^s, но не делится на p^(s + 1)
unsigned factorial_exponent(unsigned n, unsigned p) {
    // assert(is_prime(p));
    unsigned e = 0;
    for (unsigned t = n / p; t > 0; t /= p) {
        e += t;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Для биномиального коэффициента:

```
// степень s такая что cnk(n, k) делится на p^s, но не делится на p^(s + 1)
unsigned binomial_exponent(unsigned n, unsigned k, unsigned p) {
    return factorial_exponent(n, p) -
           (factorial_exponent(k, p) + factorial_exponent(n - k, p));
}
```

[Вычисление φ(cnk(n, k))](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) выполняется по разложению на простые:

```
// phi(cnk(n, k))
uint64_t phi_cnk(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
    product_t phi = 1;

    for (primes_t it(n + 1); it; ++it) {
        const unsigned p = *it;
        const unsigned e = binomial_exponent(n, k, p);
        if (e > 0) {
            phi *= p - 1;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < e - 1; ++i) {
                phi *= p;
            }
        }
    }
    return phi;
}
```

Вся программа довольно большая - нужны [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), извлечение квадратного корня и контроль переполнения при умножении:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

unsigned isqrt(unsigned a) {
    unsigned low = 0;
    unsigned high = std::min(
        1U << (std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits / 2),
        a / 2U + 2
    ); 

    while (low < high - 1) {
        const unsigned mid = (high + low) / 2U;
        if (mid * mid > a) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid;
        }
    }
    return low;
}

class primes_t {
public:
    primes_t(unsigned n) : n(n), sqrt_n(isqrt(n)), sieve(n, true), i(2) {}
    operator bool() const { return i < n; }
    unsigned operator *() const { return i; }

    primes_t &operator ++() {
        if (i <= sqrt_n) {
            for (unsigned j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }

        for (++i; i < n; ++i) {
            if (sieve[i]) {
                return *this;
            }
        }

        i = n;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    unsigned n;
    unsigned sqrt_n;
    std::vector<bool> sieve;
    unsigned i;
};

unsigned factorial_exponent(unsigned n, unsigned p) {
    // assert(is_prime(p));
    unsigned e = 0;
    for (unsigned t = n / p; t > 0; t /= p) {
        e += t;
    }
    return e;
}

unsigned binomial_exponent(unsigned n, unsigned k, unsigned p) {
    return factorial_exponent(n, p) -
           (factorial_exponent(k, p) + factorial_exponent(n - k, p));
}

class product_t {
public:
    product_t(unsigned product) : product(product) {}
    void operator *=(unsigned factor) {
        if (std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() / product < factor) {
            throw std::overflow_error("overflow");
        }
        product *= factor;
    }
    operator uint64_t() const { return product; }
private:
    uint64_t product;
};

uint64_t phi_cnk(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
    product_t phi = 1;

    for (primes_t it(n + 1); it; ++it) {
        const unsigned p = *it;
        const unsigned e = binomial_exponent(n, k, p);
        if (e > 0) {
            phi *= p - 1;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < e - 1; ++i) {
                phi *= p;
            }
        }
    }
    return phi;
}

int main() {
    unsigned n, k;
    if (!(std::cin >> n >> k)) {
        std::cerr << "input error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    uint64_t phi;
    try {
        phi = phi_cnk(n, k);
    } catch (const std::overflow_error &e) {
        std::cerr << "overflow\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << phi << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 phi-cnk.cpp 
>
> $ echo 69 34 | ./a.out
> 11368549725319987200
>
> $ time echo 1000000000 2 | ./a.out
> 129729340800000000
>
> real  0m10.228s
> user  0m10.188s
> sys   0m0.036s
> ```